# How can I take a txt input in JS and turn it into an int array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Still learning the small things, mercy please.
If there's some input.txt file in the same directory, what's the command to fetch that and then how do I turn it into an array of separate values?(Not sure if in JS to use numbers in methods afterwards I'd need to declare that they aren't a string?)
An example input would be something like:
+4
-2
-47
+15
So just to have them in a workable var x=[4,-2,-47,15]; Will figure out separating the plus signs at some point, just for the sake of simplicity that's what I'm going for.

Comment: are you talking about `node.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a Node.js program:

Load the file using the FS module (readFileSync may be enough if you don't care about concurrency), split the resulting string on some divider with string.split(), and use parseInt(string, radix) to turn the strings into numbers (there is no integer type in JavaScript). Push these into an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run this locally you can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in modern browsers.

```
// Grab the file
fetch('text.txt')

  // Parse the contents to text
  .then(res => res.text())

  // call the `processText` function
  .then(processText)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

function processText(text) {

  // Split the text into an array on the line break
  const arr = text.split('\n');

  // Convert each element into an integer
  // with the correct sign
  const mapped = arr.map(Number);
  console.log(mapped); // Array(4) [ 4, -2, -47, 15 ]
}
```